# Is the following parabolic operator a Fredholm operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Considered the following differential operator $L:X \to Y$

$$L u :=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right).$$

**Is it Fredholm?** If so, **which candidates would we have for $X$ and $Y$**?

I think the answer might be yes, since in one-dimension the operator $A:C^2[0, \pi] \to C[0, \pi]$, $Af = u'' + \lambda\, u$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just extend your example to this setting?

Let $L:C^{2,1}([a,b];[0,T])\rightarrow C([a,b];[0,T])$, where $f\in C^{2,1}([a,b];[0,T])$ means that $f$ is $C^2$ in the spatial variable and $C^1$ in the temporal variable.

Comment: I think this might not be so trivial. This must be proved. We know that elliptic operators are Fredholm operators (of course this claim requires choosing appropriate $X$ and $Y$). However, for parabolic operators, it is not so trivial.